# Why are words represented by frequency counts before embedding?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, text-mining, word-embeddings

Before getting vector representations of words by embedding, the words are mapped to numbers. These numbers are chosen to be the frequency of that word in the dataset. Why does this convention exist? Does it have any effects, or is it arbitrary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a general principle in linguistics and consequently in NLP: the meaning of a word is represented by the context of the word, i.e. the words around it. [edit] In NLP this principle is the basis of [distributional semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributional_semantics), which is used in every NLP application involving semantics (almost of them).

This means that statistically the meaning of a word can be represented by a distribution of frequencies/probabilities over the vocabulary of all its possible context words. This principle is generalized to a full text: the meaning of the text is represented as the frequency distribution of the words it contains.

Thus it's very meaningful to use the word frequency: it represents the "importance" of the word in the text and taking together the "importance" of all the words gives a representation of the meaning of the text.

Comment: Thank you for the answer this helps. Could you give some clarification because as it stands this sounds like circular reasoning: frequencies of word represent their meaning, thus the meaning of the full text is represented as the frequency distribution of the words it contains, thus word frequencies are meaningful. I know I am just misunderstanding something but could you clarify either why individual word frequencies or frequency distributions of full texts are meaningful?

Comment: @JohnS Sorry if my explanation is not clear, I'm not very satisfied with it myself but I don't really see how to improve it. My last sentence is just a conclusion, so the logic is just this: the word frequency represents how important a word is in a text, and the frequency distribution for all the words (over some fixed vocabulary) represents the meaning of the text.

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on what embedding algorithm you are referring to, but you often decide your vocabulary size in advance, and any words are given the `OOV` (out of vocab) or `UNK` (unknown) token.

Sorting your vocabulary by frequency (in a representative sample of data) is the most sensible way to decide which words make the cut, and which get discarded.

> Does it have any effects, or is it arbitrary?

As described above, it is arbitrary, and you should get identical results by randomly shuffling your word list, and then using that.

As a possible aside, embeddings now often use the output of SentencePiece or a similar algorithm like BPE. These work by being given a target vocabulary size, and breaking words up into tokens, to avoid having any UNK tokens. [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/sentencepiece-tokenizer-demystified-d0a3aac19b15) looks like a good article, or searching for BPE or SentencePiece. but the basic idea is that the most frequent strings of characters become tokens in their own right. So (for English) the letters 'a' to 'z' are tokens, but then things like 'it', 'and', 'the' and so on will become tokens. But if the corpus is all about American cities, you might get multiple word strings such as 'New York' become a token too.

But, again, the actual number assigned to each token is arbitrary.